# Probability of HTHT in n coin flips

Tags: probability

What is the probability of finding the sequence HTHT in $n$ flips of a coin? By brute force I get

- $n=4: \frac{1}{2^4}$
- $n=5: \frac{2(2)}{2^5}$
- $n=6: \frac{2^2(3)-1}{2^6}$
- $n=7: \frac{2^3(4)-2}{2^7}$
- $n=8: \frac{2^4(5)-6}{2^8}$

I hoped to extract a pattern but counting gets messy.

**EDIT:** My original counts for $n=7$ and $n=8$ are, as noted in the comments, incorrect. Recounting I get
\begin{align}
\frac{2^3(4)-4}{2^7}\ \text{for}\ n=7\ \text{and}\ \frac{2^4(5)-12}{2^8}\ \text{for}\ n=8
\end{align}
which agrees with the comment below.

Comment: Sorry, could you be clearer when stating your problem?

Comment: $1,4,11,28,68,158,357...$ Sequence not found in OEIS. Note that your counts for $n=7$ and $n=8$ are incorrect.

Comment: @DanielMathias If you take each term minus twice its predecessor, so $1,2,3,6,12,22,41$ etc., I think you get [OEIS A112575](https://oeis.org/A112575)

Comment: @Henry Nice find. The relation is confirmed.

Comment: and $\frac{1}{2^4},\frac{2}{2^5},\frac{3}{2^6},\frac{6}{2^7},\frac{12}{2^8},\frac{22}{2^9},\frac{41}{2^{10}}, \ldots$ are the probabilities of needing $n$ rolls *but not fewer*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n$ be the number of sequences that don't include the pattern $HTHT$. Then

$$A_n = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 &1} T^n  {\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 &0}}^{t} \tag1$$

where

$$T= \pmatrix{ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &0 
} \tag2$$

Eq $(1)$ is obtained by counting recursively the "allowed" sequences that have $(0,1,2,3)$  trailing matching characters.

Some values for $A_n$, from $n=0$ to $n=10$: $(1, 2,4,8,15,28,53,100,188,354,667)$

This is OEIS sequence [A118870](https://oeis.org/A118870).

Then the desired probability is

$$ p_n = 1 - \frac{A_n}{2^{n}}$$

I don't think there is a simple formula to express $(1)$ for arbitrary $n$

I'd expect that $p_n \le 1 - (15/16)^{n-3}$

Comment: The generating function $\frac{1+z^2}{1-2z+z^2-2z^3+z^4}$ is given in the OEIS entry; we can also find it from your matrix $T$, since $\sum_{n\ge 0}A_n z^n = (1,1,1,1)(\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n T^n) (1,0,0,0)^t = (1,1,1,1) (I - zT)^{-1} (1,0,0,0)^t$. We can use this to get an explicit formula, but it's not nice; the dominant term of $A_n$ is proportional to $\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}-1}+1\right)\right)^n$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov that dominant term can also be obtained from the largest eigenvalue of $T$

Comment: Sir, please help me with the problem at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797044/distribution-of-the-number-of-trials-required-for-the-first-occurrence-of-the-ev

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the following works.

Let $N_k$ be the number of sequences of length $k$ that end *for the first time* in HTHT.

Now, the number of sequences of length $k$ that end in HTHT (possibly not for the first time) is $2^{k-4}$.  However, many of these had proper prefixes that ended in HTHT, and we have to subtract these out:

- $N_{k-2}$, the prefixes of length $k-2$ that end in HTHT.
- $N_{k-4}$, the prefixes of length $k-4$ that end in HTHT.
- $2N_{k-5}$, twice the prefixes of length $k-5$ that end in HTHT (because they are followed by an arbitrary result on flip number $k-4$).
- $4N_{k-6}$, four times the prefixes of length $k-6$ that end in HTHT (because they are followed by an arbitrary result on flips number $k-5$ and $k-4$).
- And so on.

We therefore have, for $k \geq 8$,

$$
N_k = 2^{k-4}-N_{k-2}-\sum_{j=4}^{k-4} 2^{j-4}N_{k-j}
$$

leading to [OEIS A112575](https://oeis.org/A112575) (with an offset), with values

$$
1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 22, 41, 78, 147, 276, 520, 980, 1845, 3474, \ldots
$$

for $k \geq 4$.  The desired probabilities are then

$$
p_k = \frac{N_k}{2^k}
$$