# What's the probability of $HTHT$ occuring before $HHTT$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

> What's the probability of $HTHT$ occuring before  $HHTT$ in a stream of $H$'s and $T$'s (both equally likely) that will stop if either of those occur? What's the mean number of throws such that $HHTT$ occurs?

Hello, I figured out that this is an instance of [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game).

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811180/probability-of-htht-in-n-coin-flips) question is also related. What makes this question hard for me is the fact that I have to somehow account for the fact that $HTHT$ occures before $HHTT$. I have to solve this using Markov chains, does someone have an idea?

Comment: I suggest you make a state transition diagram for a Markox chain with states $$\big\{\emptyset,H,HT,HH,HTH,HHT,HTHT,HHTT\big\}$$ with $HTHT,HHTT$ absorbing. You're trying to find the probability of being absorbed into the state $HTHT.$

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice. However, I fail to compute the probability of being absorbed into $HHTT$. I guess I could follow every path and use Chapman-Kolmogorov ... Is there a trick for computing the absorption probability?

Comment: I've seen several questions that compute the expectation by "divide et impera" using conditional expectation. I'll try approaching this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is an elaboration on the comment by @MatthewH.

Let $P_i$ denote the probability of hitting $HTHT$ first when in state $i$.  The equations relating the probabilities are

\begin{align*}
P_{\emptyset} &= \frac 12(P_H + P_{\emptyset}) \\
P_H &= \frac 12 (P_{HH}+P_{HT}) \\
P_{HT} &= \frac 12 (P_{HTH}+P_{\emptyset}) \\
P_{HH} &= \frac 12 (P_{HH} + P_{HHT}) \\
P_{HTH} &= \frac 12 (P_{HH} + P_{HTHT}) \\
P_{HHT} &= \frac 12 (P_{HTH} + P_{HHTT}) \\
P_{HTHT} &= 1 \\
P_{HHTT} &= 0.
\end{align*}
This is a large linear system, but it can be solved fairly easily by substitution.  The solution I found is
\begin{align*}
P_{\emptyset} = P_H &= \frac 49 \\
P_{HT} &= \frac 59 \\
P_{HH} &= \frac 13 \\
P_{HTH} &= \frac 23 \\
P_{HHT} &= \frac 13,
\end{align*}
but please double check to make sure I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Using $P_{\emptyset}=a$, $P_H=b$, $P_{HT}=c$, $P_{HH}=d$, $P_{HTH}=w$, $P_{HHT}=x$, $P_{HTHT}=y$ and $P_{HHTT}=z, your result is verified by: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a%3D1%2F2%28b%2Ba%29%2C+b%3D1%2F2%28d%2Bc%29%2C+c%3D1%2F2%28w%2Ba%29%2C+d%3D1%2F2%28d%2Bx%29%2C+w%3D1%2F2%28d%2By%29%2C+x%3D1%2F2%28w%2Bz%29%2C+y%3D1%2C+z%3D0

Comment: How can I combine these probabilities to obtain the probability in question? @user6247850

Comment: @Analysis The probability in question is $P_{\emptyset}$: The probability of reaching $HTHT$ when not conditioning on being in any state.